# Can I rotate an object clockwise or counterclockwise around its center handle using shortcut keyboard keys in Illustrator CS5?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts

I am reproducing a poster from an image that I've placed in the background. There are a lot of rotated objects, graphics, text all of which I would like to line up with the original image.  I've been rotating manually and I sometimes have the need to fine tune the position and rotation by small increments.  Position is straight forward with arrows.  Are there any shortcut keys for rotating?  The fine tuning is a bit tricky for me because I am using a trackball mouse (CST 1545 trackball - Very comfortable but not as precise)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select the object
2. Double click the Rotate Tool
3. Tick the Preview box
4. Use the arrow keys in the Angle field

You can also Option/Alt-click with the Rotate Tool on the artboard (rather than step 2 above) to set the rotation point, then bring up the dialog box.

Comment: Thanks. It's very slow on objects with effects but it works.

Comment: Turn off the visibility for the effects in the Appearance Panel, rotate, then turn visibility back on. This helps unless you're trying to line up the effects with something. Usually you merely need to turn off visibility for glows and shadows or raster effects.

Comment: Is there seriously no direct keyboard shortcut to rotate the selected object a degree to the right or left? I can move objects with the arrow keys but I can't rotate them? Arrrrrrgh, this is going to drive me insane.

Answer (score 3):

There is keyboard shortcuts for this: select the object, press <kbd>R</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring up `Rotate` tool dialog, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to enable `Preview` checkbox, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to return focus back to `Angle` field. You may keep holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> button while pressing <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd>. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when done.